# Dynamic search : Pandas data frame query

Tags: python, pandas, string

I am trying to take a string (word or phrase) user input to search for sub string in a particular column to query the results. How can i make it dynamic ? i.e. i want to keep adding the words as new queries to locate the item without having to define it.

eg. if input is - 'word1'; 
it returns all rows with 'word1' in df['column']

and if input is - 'word1 word2 wordn'; 
it returns all rows with the query as below :

```
x = input("Type to search for item : ")  # input phrase or word
words = x.split(' ')

query = df.loc[(df['Column'].str.contains(words[0]))
           &(df['Column'].str.contains(words[1]))
           &(df['Column'].str.contains(words[n]))
           ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
submasks = [df['Column'].str.contains(s) for s in words]
combined = np.vstack(submasks).all(axis=0)
df[combined]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider [**`Series.str.contains`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) using regex with `AND` logic:

```
words_pattern = r"(" + ")(".join(words) + ")"

sub_df = df.loc[df['char'].str.contains(words_pattern, regex=True)]
```

Alternatively, per warning in using regex string groupings, use [**`Series.str.extract`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
words_pattern = r"(" + ")(".join(words) + ")"

res = df['char'].str.extract(words_pattern)
sub_df = df.loc[res.dropna().index]
```